# Index confusion in python

Tags: python

Hello folks am new to python development.I have wrote a sample code:

```
mylist = ['something','baby','car']
for i,n in mylist:
    mylist[i] = mylist[i]+1
    print i,n
```

I know `i` is the index in the list so it will execute up to the number of elements in the list.But when I execute the script I get type error...

In this code  the index of the list is inceremented by one... So the expected result is.

```
0 something
1 baby
2 car
```

Instead of that i got a typeerror..Please help me in solving this..Any help would be appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This :

```
mylist = ['something','baby','car']
for i,n in mylist:
    mylist[i] = mylist[i]+1
    print i,n
```

raises a `ValueError` ("Too many values to unpack") on the second line.

If you just add `enumate` on this second line, ie `for i,n in enumerate(mylist):`, then you get a `TypeError` on the next line, because you are trying to add a string (`mylist[i]`) and an integer (`i`). The point is: what you want to increment is `i`, not `mylist[i]` (which is the same thing as `n` fwiw), so it should be:

```
for i, n in enumerate(mylist):
    i = i + 1
    print i, n
```

BUT you don't have to go thru such complications to print out "index+1 : item at index+1", all you need is to pass the optional `start` argument to `enumerate`:

```
mylist = ['something','baby','car']
for i, n in enumerate(mylist, 1):
    print i, n
```

Comment: so what will be the result is i give mylist[i] ..is it possible in python ?...can you tell me its use ?

Comment: @user3501595 : this is fully documented, you know. cf https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy for a start.

Comment: thanks ..and can you tell me in which situation do i wanna add mylist[i] = mylist[i]+1...Please ..

Answer (score 3):

Very close, just missing [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)--

```
for i,n in enumerate(mylist):
```

However, the code above will attempt to add an integer to a string; this will throw a new error. If you are trying to push elements back, you would want `mylist[i] = mylist[i+1]` (note you would have to have a case to catch the last element)

Comment: @user3501595, Alternatively, you can do: `for i in mylist:` and then `print i,mylist[i]`

Comment: @sshashank124 do you mean `for i in range(0,len(mylist)):` ?

Comment: Since we have `enumerate`, there are few reasons (well, _good_ reasons I mean) to use `for i in range(len(mylist)):`. The above use case is definitly not one of them.